# TypoScript BeUserLogin Not working in other domain/rootline

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want to add some scripts in the FE if the backend user is logged in. I did the following code, it works fine in my main rootline pages. But I added another root pages and subpages and assign one subdomain to that rootpages, my script is not working there (only in newly created rootlines).

```
[globalVar = TSFE : beUserLogin > 0]
page.headerData.1000 = TEXT
page.headerData.1000.value (
// Scripts
)
[global]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the login is bound to the domain, that won't work on other domains. As a solution log in at another domain as well.